# Regular expressions: transferring the data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a profile page that changes all `<strong>Title</strong>` tags into `<input type="text" value="Title">` and `<p>Content</p>` tags into `<textarea>Content</textarea>` tags.

This works great with this:

```
$(this).html(function(i, h) {
  return h
    .replace(/<strong>/g, "<input type=\"text\" value=\"")
    .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "\" class=\"profile-header\">")
    .replace(/<p>/g, "<textarea>")
    .replace(/<\/p>/g, "</textarea>");
});
```

However, I need an ID for each set of `<strong>` and `<p>` tags (as they represent different parts of the profile).  The issue I'm having is adding an ID for these, which I have put on the `<strong>` tags like this: `<strong data-id="0">` but can't work out why the regular expression I'm using doesn't work properly.

Here's what I have so far, hopefully you can see what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$(this).html(function(i, h) {
  return h
    .replace(/<strong data-id=\"(\i+)\">/g, "<input $1 type=\"text\" value=\"")
    .replace(/<\/strong>/g, "\" class=\"profile-header\">")
    .replace(/<p>/g, "<textarea>")
    .replace(/<\/p>/g, "</textarea>");
});
```

And just for reference, this is how I am returning the HTML back to its original state (and how the data is saved):

```
$(".column.about input").each(function() {

    // Get the titles and content from the inputs and textareas
    var content_id = $(this).data("id");
    var title = $(this).val();
    var content = $(this).next().val();

    // We're changing the content first so we don't loose $(this)
    $(this).next().after("<p>" + content + "</p>").remove();
    $(this).after("<strong data-id=\"" + content_id + "\">" + title + "</strong>").remove();

    $.post("../includes/ajax.php", { action: "updateProfile", section: "about", id: content_id, title: title, content: content }).done(function(data) {

        if(data != "saved") {

        throwErrorMessage(data);

      }

    });

});
```

Comment: It might be easier to work with if you `.each` `"strong"` and `"p"` - then use `insertBefore` - you can then easily transfer attributes with `.attr`, and by the use of classes on the `input/textarea` deal with hiding the originals (i.e. `.editInput + p,.editInput + strong { display:none; }`

Comment: [Yeah, don't try to parse/manipulate HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: So my best bet is to stop using regex and copy the `.each(function() {` I used to change it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have done (without regular expressions):

```
$(".column.about strong").each(function() {

    // Get the titles and content from the strong and p tags
    var content_id = $(this).data("id");
    var title = $(this).text();
    var content = $(this).next().text();

    // We're changing the content first so we don't loose $(this)
    $(this).next().after("<textarea>" + content + "</textarea>").remove();
    $(this).after("<input type=\"text\" data-id=\"" + content_id + "\" value=\"" + title + "\">").remove();

});
```

And it works. Happy days.